# Insert value into a dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How do I rewrite the last two lines of the below code, so that the last line does not overwrite the second to last line?

Desired result is that the "color" column will have either "pink" or "orange" values put in depending on which condition is met: "KOM" or "Top 10".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def contains_BO(seg_effs):  
        # check if segment efforts for activity contain any best overall effort
        for eff in seg_effs:
            rank = eff['kom_rank']
            if rank != None:
                if rank == 1:
                    return "KOM"
                else:
                    return "Top 10"

activities = pd.read_pickle('strava.pk1') 
activities['color'] = np.where(activities['segment_efforts'].map(contains_BO) == 'KOM', "orange", "grey")
activities['color'] = np.where(activities['segment_efforts'].map(contains_BO) == 'Top 10', "pink", "grey")
```

Answer (score 1):

You use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(4), "b": ["x", "x", "y", "y"]})
df

   a  b
0  0  x
1  1  x
2  2  y
3  3  y

# assign 5 to rows of "a" where "b" == "x"
df.loc[df["b"] == "x", "a"] = 5
df

   a  b
0  5  x
1  5  x
2  2  y
3  3  y
```

Alternatively you can create a new column out of a dict of values:

```
df["val"] = df["b"].map({"x": 5, "y": 6})

df

   a  b  val
0  5  x    5
1  5  x    5
2  2  y    6
3  3  y    6
```

[map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) also supports functions if you need more complex logic.